# Access Sitecore items via .NET web service

Tags: .net, web-services, sitecore

Has anyone had luck with using a .NET web service to access Sitecore items? I have a number of web applications on my server that are still in Coldfusion. I'd like to be able to call a web service to pull down items, but when I tried to do this I got an exception "Sitecore.Data.Items.Item cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor."

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible. A Sitecore.Data.Items.Item is a very robust (read: filled with methods that do more Sitecore DAL calls) class and really not suitable for being returned from a web service. Why are you doing this? Perhaps there is a simpler implementation?

Comment: I'm definitely open to something simpler. Basically I have a number of content items in Sitecore that need to be displayed in a Coldfusion application. In my particular instance I have all my news articles in Sitecore, but there are a number of Coldfusion applications that, in one way shape or form, pull news items.

Comment: lots of options offered to answer this Q but not clear enough feedback to give the man a good answer.

Comment: That's not really a good reason to down vote the question though, just because you're upset that I didn't accept your answer. I haven't found anything that works well for me yet and have had to move on as I can't just linger on this forever. I considered closing the question, but chose to leave it open as maybe someone else could be helped by the information here.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at Sitecore standard web service, you can find it under /sitecore/shell/WebService folder of your solution. It offers some basic operations with Sitecore items and fields, but it is often enough for pulling or saving data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I think I've basically concluded this can't be done though.

Comment: can you explain further why the standard service won't work for you? based on everything you're saying here, it sounds like the best solution

Comment: I'm sure it would work in some way. The key here is that I want to be able to reuse methods I've already written to retrieve a specific set of items that are used inside of a web control on one of my sitecore pages. Basically I don't want to have two different pieces of code to maintain that do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I answered this on the [SDN forum](http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum//ShowPost.aspx?PostID=28446) as well. You can create your own wrapper object which is filled with a Sitecore item and sets its members. The hard part will be creting your members and assigning them from the real Sitecore item. If you want everything then I think it will be difficult. If you just want some stuff then its doable. E.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class SitecoreItem {
  public string ID;
  // more members

  SitecoreItem(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item scItem) {
      this.ID = scItem.ID;
      // assign more members from the true Sitecore item
  }

}
```

Then in your WS method fill a new instance with your actual Sitecore item and return it:

```
return new SitecoreItem(actualSCItem);
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Any ideas on how to make it more generic though? I'd like to have something that I can use for any item to return all fields. I realize you said this would be more difficult, but do you have any ideas as to how to start going about this?

Comment: You cannot serialize the Sitecore.Data.Items.Item class so your only way would be to create a wrapper and do the work of assigning the members. This solution is generic though if you take the time to go through all of the properties. The only other option would be to use the built-in WS Yan mentioned

Comment: Can the Fields class be serialized? This would be the key for me. I need to get all the field information and not every template contains the same fields.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. I'm gonna guess you can't because there are many type of actual fields that can exist and you'd need to serialize those and their properties. The `Fields` property is a `Sitecore.Collections.FieldCollection` so you'd need to serialize that as well.

Answer (score 1):

If both the serialiser and the deserialiser have access to the Sitecore database, then you can very easily create a wrapper that just serialises the ID, database name, version and language.  Then upon deserialisation on the other end, you can re-fetch the same Sitecore item from the database using that information.

If the deserialiser doesn't have access to the database at all, then it really depends on what your needs are for using the data.  I typically loop over all the fields (remember to use `item.Fields.ReadAll()` first), and store them in a dictionary for easy access.  For serialisation, I convert that into a `List<T>` of key value pairs and ignore the `Dictionary` member (since it can't be serialised) and then re-populate it on deserialisation.  I keep a few other properties like ID, Language, Version, Template, Path, etc. on the class too.

Alternatively, if you create a whole model class library so that each template is mapped to a class (some people do), you can (probably) serialise those straight off since they're (probably) no longer bound to a Sitecore item.

Comment: The whole class library thing is exactly what we do. Each template has a class and each field is mapped to a property. We made a tool in Sitecore to build these automatically. I recommend that approach but only if you can automate it. If not, then that's just as tedious as creating the wrapper for each member of the Sitecore item.